# Neo4j not starting on Raspberry Pi (memory issues and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, neo4j, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to install Neo4j on my Raspberry Pi. The [installation](https://debian.neo4j.com/) for the latest version worked great so far.
When I tried `neo4j start` I received this error message but was able to resolve it by setting `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=12m` and `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=12m` and `dbms.memory.pagecache.size=1g` (allthough that feels wrong to me since my Pi has 8GB of memory):

```
nohup: ignoring input
2021-01-26 21:54:18.409+0000 ERROR Invalid memory configuration - exceeds physical memory. Check the configured values for dbms.memory.pagecache.size and db>
2021-01-26 21:54:18.436+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2021-01-26 21:54:18.437+0000 INFO  Stopped.
```

**Now**, when I try to start neo4j I get this error in my logs:

```
nohup: ignoring input
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.neo4j.configuration.GraphDatabaseSettings
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:105)
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:90)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:35)
2021-01-26 22:20:55.271+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityBootstrapper] Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
2021-01-26 22:20:55.290+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityBootstrapper] Stopped.
```

I have now been trying to google the problem for a couple hours but I feel like I don't really know what to look for.

My setup:

- Raspberry Pi 4 (8 GB memory)
- Ubuntu Server (`uname -a` returns `Linux ubuntu 5.8.0-1011-raspi #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 15 08:53:29 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`)
- Java 11 (`java -version` returns  `openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10, mixed mode)`)
- Neo4j version 4.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trying it seems like it is a problem with the latest Neo4j version (4.2.3).
I now installed version 4.0.11 and it works without any problems.